# What do these icons mean for Sharepoint sites?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, sharepoint-server, file-icons

I am working within a Sharepoint site that has a bunch of sub-sites, and trying to create my own sub-site.  The other sub-sites have some standard sub-navigations like "Announcements", "Calendar", "Documents", etc, and this icon:

[image: cat.gif]

When I created my own sub-site, there were none of the sub-navigations, and it was represented by this icon:

[image: SharePointFoundation16.png]

It seems like I'm doing something wrong.  What do these two icons mean, or what is the difference?

Comment: Where are you viewing these icons (what page or in what context)?

Comment: @JohnChapman this is in the tree view you see after clicking "Manage Content And Structure".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top one is a Site icon.

The bottom one is a SharePoint Site icon.  It was a red-green-blue-yellow people in 2007.

Comment: I see ... the strange thing is that I managed to create a Sharepoint Site by clicking "New Site" next to the Site icon.  Can you tell me roughly the difference between the two?

Comment: The top one is associated with Publishing Sites and People icon is assocaited with Collaborative sites (Workspace, team & Wiki).  It will determine, Features turned on by-default, pressentation and layout of the site to name a few things.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the first icon is from older versions of SharePoint and the second is the 2010 version of it.